# Failed to convert a field type to INT in Python

Tags: python, type-conversion

I'm using Google Colab to run a k-Means Cluster Analysis which needs some metrics set as INT/FLOAT. The data used in this analysis was imported from a Google Sheet using **gspread** package resulting all columns' type set to be **Object** as shown below:

[image]
[image]

And then, I'm trying to change their data type into appropriate ones so that so that I can process the analysis. For example I'm gonna turn amount and count into INT. I'm using the code below:

[image]

All of the conversions are successfully done except for the count column which remains as Object. Is there any specific explanation for this error? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a string then an int : final_data.count = final_data['count'].applymap(int
)

Comment: Hi Raed, I've tried to convert it into FLOAT but had the exact same result. Also, I've tried to use int() but it gave me an error: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>. Any idea why this happened? Thank you

Comment: I think I've found a solution, convert it to a string then to an int

Comment: final_data.count = final_data['count'].astype(str).astype(int)

Comment: tell me if this helps i edited the answer to fit

Comment: Hi, I've just tried using final_data['amount'].astype(str).astype(int) but it returned the same output

Comment: Same output, Raed. I think this error might've come from the data in Google Sheet, but I don't know why

Comment: try   .applymap()   instead of astype

Comment: final_data.count  = final_data['count'].applymap(int)

Comment: It gave me an error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'

Comment: i really aren't sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239549/discussion-between-raed-ali-and-iren-ramadhan).